# MP3 файлы в Java

Tags: java

Есть ли способ проиграть музыку в java? Только без xml, и т.п. Только Java.

Comment: Alex Chermenin, не работает!!!!

Comment: Так как используется JavaFX необходима предварительная инициализация. Самое простое - добавить статический блок в классе, где располагается `main` метод: `static { new JFXPanel(); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать классы `Media` и `MediaPlayer` из Java FX:

```
String bip = "bip.mp3";
Media hit = new Media(new File(bip).toURI().toString());
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(hit);
mediaPlayer.play();
```

Оригинальный ответ на SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045384/playing-mp3-and-wav-in-java

PS: Так как используется JavaFX необходима предварительная инициализация. Самое простое - добавить статический блок в классе, где располагается `main` метод: `static { new JFXPanel(); }`